# Help in proof for checking for convergence of sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

This is a homework problem for which I think I've missed the point or have incorrectly done the proof (or both).  There are two parts to the problem: Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence with $a_n \ge 0,$ for all $n$.

Part 1:
Suppose that $a_n \rightarrow 0$.  Show that $\sqrt{a_n}\rightarrow 0$.  I recognized that these are actually two different sequences.  Here is my proof.
**Proof**
Let $(b_n)=\sqrt{a_n}$ and $\forall a\in (a_n), a\ge 0$.
By assumption, $(a_n) \rightarrow 0$.
By definition of *Square Root*, $\forall b_n, b_n < a_n$.
So, since $b_n < a_n$ and $(a_n) \rightarrow 0, (b_n) \rightarrow 0 \square$.

Part 2:
Suppose that $a_n \rightarrow L$.  Show that $\sqrt{a_n}\rightarrow \sqrt{L}$.

Assuming I did things correctly in part 1, shouldn't this be a virtual *ditto*?  My teacher gave this *hint* which makes me think I'm way off base:
*you can assume that $L\ne 0$.  Use that $\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y} = \frac{x-y}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}}$*.

Since my proof in part 1 didn't use anything like this, I'm assuming I'm off in the weeds.  Since this homework hasn't yet been graded, I'll need hints rather than solutions.  Thanks.

Comment: In part 1, $\sqrt{a_n}>a_n$ for $0< a_n<1$.  For example, $\sqrt{1/4}=1/2>1/4$.  In part 2, I think you mean $\sqrt{a_n}\to\sqrt{L}$.

Comment: @ForgotALot you're correct.  I'm fixing that now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

For an all-encompassing proof with $L \geqslant 0$ note that

$$|\sqrt{a_n} - \sqrt{L}|^2 \leqslant |\sqrt{a_n} - \sqrt{L}||\sqrt{a_n} + \sqrt{L}| = |a_n - L|$$

Comment: I understand what you're saying. What I don't understand is the "magic" or the why you know to do this.  Is it simply going back to the definition of *convergence*?  That is, namely, to show convergence, we must show that at some $N\in\mathbb{N}, \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n\ge N, |a_n - L| \lt \epsilon$.  Is this why?

Comment: Yes and more to the point we have to show $|\sqrt{a_n} - \sqrt{L}| < \epsilon$ for sufficiently large $n$.  What we are given is that $a_n \to L$ so we know we can make $|a_n - L|$ small.  In the end we have to relate $|\sqrt{a_n} - \sqrt{L}|$ to $|a_n - L|$.  Using what I showed, you can see that if $|a_n - L| < \epsilon^2$ then $|\sqrt{a_n} - \sqrt{L}| < \epsilon$.  The first condition can be met for sufficiently large $n$ since $a_n \to L$.

Answer (score 0):

For the first one it is NOT true that $\sqrt{x_n} < x_n$ but the limit is still zero all the same.  Are you allowed to use the fact that you can "pass a limit through a continuous function"?  If so... then 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} g(x_n) = g(\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n) = g(0)$$
where $g(x)=\sqrt{x}$ and we know that $g(0)=0$.  Please let me know if you are not aware of this result or cannot use it.

Comment: I had suspected that my reasoning was incorrect.  I do not know if this would not be permitted.  However, I didn't think of using such a construct.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/560307/prove-that-sqrtx-is-continuous-on-its-domain-0-infty

This proves that $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$ and your textbook should have a proof that the first equals sign is true in my centred equation.