# How to prove that $\sqrt x$ is continuous in $[0,\infty)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

I am trying to prove that

> $\sqrt x$ is continuous in $[0,\infty)$.

I have started writing the following proof:
Given $x_0 \in [0,\infty)$ and $\epsilon > 0$. We have to show that there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that for every $x \in (x_0 - \delta,x_0 +\delta)$, $\sqrt x \in (\sqrt x_0 - \epsilon, \sqrt x_0 + \epsilon)$.

So, $| \sqrt x - \sqrt x_0 | = \frac {| (\sqrt x - \sqrt x_0)(\sqrt x + \sqrt x_0) |}{| \sqrt x + \sqrt x_0 |} =  \frac {| x - x_0 |}{| \sqrt x + \sqrt x_0 |}$

I am not sure how to continue from here..
I could take $M = max\{ x,x_0 \}$ and $\delta = 2M  \epsilon$ but this is unnecessary if $x,x_0 > 1$.

Should I split to cases? $x,x_0 > 1$, $0 < x,x_0 < 1$ etc..
Should I dea with $x_0 = 0$ separately with a right neighborhood $[0,\delta)$?

I feel like I am over complicating this..

What is the simplest way to define $\delta$?

Thanks!!

Comment: Various solutions at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/560307/42969.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct, technically it translates into $M:=\min(\max(x_0,x),1)$. Unnecessary doesn't make it bad. To make it really simple, you should use the fact that this is the inverse of $x\mapsto x^2$ on $[0,\infty)$ which is a continuous and monotonic function (a homeomorphism in fancy language), which must have a continuous and monotonic inverse.

Comment: Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/569928/42969.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will prove the stronger result that the function is uniformly continuous. If $x <\epsilon ^{2} /4$ and $x_o <\epsilon ^{2} /4$ then  then $|\sqrt x -\sqrt {x_0}| <\epsilon /2+\epsilon/ 2=\epsilon$. Otherwise $|\sqrt x -\sqrt {x_0}| \leq \frac {2|x-x_0|} {\epsilon}$ from the inequality you have derived. Hence $|\sqrt x -\sqrt {x_0}|<\epsilon$ if $|x-x_0| <\epsilon^{2}/2$.

Answer (score 6):

For $x_{0}\neq 0$, we have
$$
|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x_{0}}|=\frac{|x-x_{0}|}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x_{0}}}\leq \frac{|x-x_{0}|}{\sqrt{x_{0}}}.
$$
So you can take $\delta=\sqrt{x_{0}}\epsilon$.

For $x_{0}=0$, we need $\sqrt{x}<\epsilon$ for $x\in(0,\delta)$, so we can take $\delta=\epsilon^{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Inverse of a continuous function is continuous on the interval hence the $\sqrt x$ is continuous off course being the inverse of square function